# How to watch for creation of nodes two levels down using Apache Curator?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

My goal is, given a `CuratorFramework` that is decorated with a path to a root node, and a `String`, to watch for events two levels down any path to that `String`.

More specifically, I would like to watch for events on any path `ROOT/<anything here>/INPUT_STRING`. I also need to watch for nodes being added in the middle layer, but I am not interested in the contents of those middle nodes (only that they appeared, so I can watch for a child to be created for the `INPUT_STRING`).

My idea was to create a `NodeCache` for each path to `ROOT/<added middle node>/INPUT_STRING` whenever a middle node is added. I thought I could then watch for middle nodes being added using a `PathChildrenCache`, but that seems like overkill since I'm not interested in the contents of the middle nodes.

Is there some better way to create a `NodeCache` for the `INPUT_STRING` two levels down? Or should I be using a `PathChildrenCache`, even though I don't care about the contents of the middle nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TreeCache` to cache/watch/listen to a tree of ZNodes. I believe that will do what you need. http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/tree-cache.html